# virtuemart 2 product pdf does not display custom fields

Tags: pdf, joomla2.5, product, virtuemart, custom-fields

I'm using VirtueMart 2.0.10 with Joomla! 2.5.6 and my problem is the autogenerated pdf documents for each product don't include my custom fields. I'm no php expert but I think theese lines in file **/components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default_pdf.php** has something to do with it, starting at line 145:

```
    <?php // Product custom_fields TODO relation to Childs
if (!empty($this->product->customfields)) { ?>
    <div class="product-fields">
    <?php
    $custom_title = null ;
    foreach ($this->product->customfields as $field){
        ?><div style="display:inline-block;" class="product-field product-field-type-<?php echo $field->field_type ?>">
        <?php if ($field->custom_title != $custom_title) { ?>
            <span class="product-fields-title" ><strong><?php echo JText::_($field->custom_title); ?></strong></span>
            <?php //echo JHTML::tooltip($field->custom_tip, $field->custom_title, 'tooltip.png');
        } ?>
        <span class="product-field-display"><?php echo $field->display ?></span>
        <span class="product-field-desc"><?php echo jText::_($field->custom_field_desc) ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php
        $custom_title = $field->custom_title;
    } ?>
    </div>
    <?php
} // Product custom_fields END ?>
```

I tested adding an else statement echoing some text after the above if statement and it executetd. So apperently there are no custom fields... but there really are...

I haven't found anyone else experiencing this problem wich I think is weird, but I don't think I have screwed something up. I HAVE made a few changes in the **/components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default.php** file.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the code that I entered in my question and replaced it with the following code from the file **/components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default.php**:

```
<?php
$custom_title = null;
foreach ($this->product->customfieldsSorted['normal'] as $field) { // I set the position to normal
if ( $field->is_hidden )
continue;
if ($field->display) {
?>
<?php if ($field->custom_title != $custom_title) { ?>
<b><?php echo JText::_($field->custom_title); ?></b><br />

<?php
if ($field->custom_tip)
echo JHTML::tooltip($field->custom_tip, JText::_($field->custom_title), 'tooltip.png');
}
?>
<?php echo $field->display ?><br />
<?php echo jText::_($field->custom_field_desc) ?><br />
<?php
$custom_title = $field->custom_title;
}
}
?>
```

I'm no expert but this worked for me. The PDF now includes the custom fields.

As you see in the comment in the code I changed the position to **'normal'**. The other positions seems to be **'ontop'** and **'onbot'**. But I won't change that setting so I leave it be.

*EDIT: I forgot to mention I added some other html-code to that segment, like `<br />` and `<b>` just for apperences. So nothing major, just to clarify that the code isn't EXACTLY like it is in the file **default.php***